# Truffle-contract: how to subscribe to certain event

Tags: truffle, events, truffle-contract

I am using [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract) for connecting between frontend and smart contract. Currently, I can call method on smart contract. But now I want to subscribe to certain events on smart contract. How can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event subscription is a new feature available from web3 1.0 beta. And now, [truffle-contract's upgrade to web3 1.0 is available as an experimental nightly build.](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/56#issuecomment-389659823) So if you are not in production and feel adventurous, you can try poking around.

If you are in production, on the other hand, you may [use web3 1.0 beta directly](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html) without truffle-contract's abstraction. [However, since major providers like MetaMask don't support web3 1.0 subscription yet(web3.js v.1.0 deprecated HttpProvider in favor of WebSocketProvider),](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3642#issue-307084613) if you'd like to use it, you may need to setup your custom WebSocket provider for now.

If all these are not your viable options, you can still [manually process the events provided in logs](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract#processing-transaction-results).

Comment: Thanks for figuring me out this :D I don't know that this feature only suppose on web3 1.0 :D

Comment: If you have time, please view my following question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49085/truffle-contract-cannot-test-method-before-real-consume-ether-method 
thanks :D