# truffle-contract: cannot test method before real consume ether method

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, truffle-contract, ganache

I am using [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract) for connecting between frontend and smart contract. Currently, I can call method on smart contract and can consume ether successfully.

```
const result = await instance.adoptCreeptomas(
aquaQuantity,
firaQuantity,
aetherQuantity,
gaiaQuantity,
referrer,
{ from: accountAddress, value: ether(sendingEther) }
```

);

But before that, I want to test method first. So I move to this method:

```
 const data = await instance.adoptCreeptomas.call(
    aquaQuantity,
    firaQuantity,
    aetherQuantity,
    gaiaQuantity,
    referrer,
    { from: accountAddress, value: ether(sendingEther) }
  );
```

But when calling this, I meet following exception:

> errors.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid JSON RPC response:
>   {"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603}}

I am using ganache for local blockchain and metamask for provider. Please help me figure out why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the difference between [`transaction`](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#transactions) and [`call`](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#calls).

The syntax `.call()` in truffle-contract is explicitly for [making a call](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#making-a-call), while the syntax of [direct call with the method name](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#making-a-transaction):

> We called the abstraction's sendCoin function directly. This will
>   result in **a transaction by default (i.e, writing data)** instead of
>   call.

I can tell from your method signature that `adoptCreeptomas` does persist some change to the network. So just get rid of `.call` and see what happens.

Comment: yes. `adoptCreeptomas` persists some data to the blockchain (and also consume ether). That why I think we should "test" method first. I based on this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call 
(Recommendation to Call first, then sendTransaction)

Comment: So that means truffle-contract doesn't support this way ?

Comment: @hqt Okay I think I misunderstood your question then. Didn't really understand what you meant by "test method first" in the first time.

Comment: If you are working with front-end, I am not sure you really need to test such stuff, because in usual provider like metamask will handle it. Anyway I'm looking into [truffle-contract code](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/develop/dist/truffle-contract.js#L300) and it looks like it will support if `web3.eth.contract` suppports.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested. I am using web3 embedded by MetaMask. As I tested, `web3.eth.contract` is existed. But I don't know how to use this method. thanks.

Comment: Do we have any reference said that metamask will do this for developer ? (testing before sending transaction). thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. I'd like to revoke that comment on metamask, it does estimate gas though. I think maybe the error has to do with ganache. Can you try this with testrpc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77840/discussion-between-viz-and-hqt).